# In Linq to Entities can you convert an IQueryable into a string of SQL?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

eg.

```
var result = myObject.Where(x => x.prop == 5);

string s = result.toSQL();
```

Result:

`s` is `"SELECT * FROM [myObjects] WHERE prop = 5"`

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980874/get-tracestring-for-your-business-objects-in-the-entity-framework

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's `IQueryable`/`ObjectQuery` you can use [`ToTraceString`](http://blog.cincura.net/227674-how-to-show-sql-command-created-by-entity-framework/). If it's IDbSet/DbSet you can use `ToString` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Using EF 6 I could not get .ToString() to return SQL for something similar to:

```
   db.Entry(parent)
   .Collection(p => p.Children)
   .Query()
   .Where(c => c.Active)
   .Load();
```

Then I remembered you can log it to debug output with:

```
db.Database.Log = (entry) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(entry);
```

Just set above before loading queries (duh) :)

**db** here is an instance of some DbContext derived class.